# Variables refuse to take values inside jQuery.get callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, asynchronous

I'm detecting if a value has been stored in localStorage (if localStorage exists), and if it's not in the database (or the user does not have a browser with localStorage) then I run an AJAX GET request.

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // there is storage
    artist = localStorage.getItem('artist');
    if (!artist) {
        // but no cache
        artist = fetchArtist();
        localStorage.setItem('artist', artist)
    }
} else {
    // there's no storage
    artist = fetchArtist();
}
function fetchArtist() {
    var fetchedArtist;
    var recentTracks;
    $.get('script.php', [], function(data) {
        recentTracks = data.recenttracks;
        fetchedArtist = ((recentTracks !== undefined) ? recentTracks.track.artist['#text'] : 'Last.fm connection failed.');
    }, 'json');
    return fetchedArtist;
}
```

script.php just gets a JSON string, which jQuery converts in to the data object. I can see the problem: because $.get is async, the fetchedArtist variable is returned before the function can assign the value I'm after, but I can't think of a tidy way of doing this (global vars maybe, but I'd really rather not). I can console.log the fetchedArtist var *inside* $.get and the value I'm after, but the fetchArtist functions always returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to asyncronize your workflow by removing the return statements from the `fetchArtist()` function because it cannot do what you need because of the async behaviour of the `$.get` request.

Try something like this:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // there is storage
    var artist = localStorage.getItem('artist');
    if (!artist) {
        // but no cache
        fetchArtist();
    } else {
        doWhatYouNeedWithArtist( artist );
    }
} else {
    // there's no storage
    fetchArtist();
}

function fetchArtist() {
    var fetchedArtist;
    var recentTracks;
    $.get('script.php', [], function(data) {
        recentTracks = data.recenttracks;
        fetchedArtist = ((recentTracks !== undefined) ? recentTracks.track.artist['#text'] : 'Last.fm connection failed.');
        if ( Modernizr.localstorage ) {
                Modernizr.localstorage.setItem('artist', fetchedArtist);
        }
        // then do your stuff
        doWhatYouNeedWithArtist( fetchedArtist );
    }, 'json');
}

function doWhatYouNeedWithArtist( artists ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps! Ciao.